# Instant messaging realization in Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, server, instant-messaging

I writting bechalor thesis on analyze and realise instant messaging system in `Java`. In my mind is first idea realise it by `SOAP` service, but in other hand I think it is simple but not appropriate, because `SOAP` provide me only one-way comunication.

In IM I want "alert" from server without asking every some period from client, I think it is waste of server capacity for answer "stupid" request for new message. I don't know other appropriate technology for realise it. I want some tips how way is correct for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Look into XMPP over socket or Socket.io might give you a good starting point. SOAP and REST are not really real time real time due to the structure of messaging, they don't keep persistent connection as websocket as you observed.

Comment: Socket.io allows comunication over inernet without public ip, trought firewall? My client will be java desktop by FX. I forget wrote it...